# Mathematica on a cluster

Tags: scripting, command-line, high-performance-clusters

I try to run mathematica on a grid. Since this is my first time working on a cluster, I have no plan what to do.

I have to run a job (pbs-file).

```
#!/bin/sh
#
#PBS -q express

module load math/mathematica/9.0.1

echo "Started"
mathematica 'pi.m'
echo "Ended"

exit 0
```

I got always the error : "Can not open display". Anyone know what to do?

The file pi.m looks like:

```
N[ Pi, 1000 ] >>"pi_result.txt"
Quit[ ]
```

Comment: I think you'd need to work with cli interface, by `math < pi.m` . This can be tested in terminal, and if it works, submit it to queue.

Comment: `math` instead of mathematica, maybe

Comment: Dear Yi Wang, think that works. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 6):

Clusters can be significantly different from each other, so I strongly recommend you talk to someone who uses the same system and ask them for help with the details.

However, there is one thing that is clearly incorrect in your job script:

To run a script with Mathematica, you need to start the kernel (command line program), not the front end (graphical interface).  Change `mathematica 'pi.m'` to `math -script pi.m`.  You can also remove `Quit` from `pi.m`.

`mathematica` starts the graphical interface, while `math` will start the kernel in command line mode and can run scripts.

Before trying to run this as a job, make sure that it can be run from the command line.  That is, test that `math -script pi.m` works when you type this on the command line.

Comment: @shrx That doesn't change the fact that it is the kernel that needs to be launched, not the front end.  The front end is auto-launched by the kernel when necessary, but this is beyond the OPs question, and I think discussing this would be more confusing than helpful at this point.